# The problem with duplicates and vampires

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

Someone asks a question that has a zillion answers. Typically,

> Why doesn't my code work? `if (a == "foo") {something();}` (Java)

The question is quickly identified as duplicate to any question regarding String comparison in Java.

The OP obtains an answer without any research, and next time will proceed identically, without searching for an answer.

Doesn't that encourage vampirism? What can I do?

Comment: Questions closed as a duplicate [appear to be counted toward the ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188291/259867), too. (And downvotes definitely do, as Oded said).

Comment: And unfortunately, many of them are answered even by high-rep users, who should know that there's already an answer out there.

Comment: Actually what I really hate about this situation is that *people who answer is not punished*. People asking question that gets closed as a duplicate in few minutes from getting asked shouldn't earn reputation, but lose it. If the duplicate is found later or much later is a different story because it probably means that it's hard to search for and I don't think people should be required to search duplicates for hours before answering, but answering a clearly obvious duplicate instead of voting to close should result is some punishment.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, yes, yes! I see lots of (often very high rep) users answering questions that are obvious duplicates. I'd love to see a solution for that.

Comment: @DavidG: I can easily see this quickly degenerating in people getting scared of answering. Is that really advisable? Just because something was obviously a duplicate to you does not mean that it was to someone else. Combined lack of expertise in this topic (and reputation does not help measuring this) and lack of luck when searching for potential duplicates or just a more cautionary approach (sometimes I waver on whether or not closing as duplicate, and given that I have Moljnir in some tags I err on the side of caution) could easily lead to answers on duplicate questions...

Comment: ... I would thus try to educate repeated offenders, but someone who errs from time to time (for a variety of reason)? It seems too harsh, and potentially harmful. I would however support simply not giving out more reputation for answers on a question closed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Very true, I only said I'd like to see a solution, but didn't provide one precisely for that reason. Potentially like the idea of stopping rep for questions marked as dupes. I just want to see the people who are rep-whoring (dislike that phrase) stop doing it in the first place. As Bakuriu said, there's no penalty for encouraging the vampires.

Comment: those darn hi-rep users answering questions should be punished.

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  Why?  Sometimes it's not immediately apparent what the duplicate question (if one exists) is.  This is a contrived example, of course, but there are certain questions which I had answered only to find that there was a duplicate for it already.

Comment: @Bakuriu what sort of world would we live in if we punish people who try to help others?

Comment: This question and the comments underneath scare me. **Guys, we're here to help, not punish.** Doling out appropriate punishment has nothing to do with the goals of this site. Maybe all take a walk around the block and think about what you're talking about here.

Comment: @DavidWallace My argument is that the people I describe are *not* really trying to help but just to earn a few easy rep points.

Comment: @deceze: I understand you point. I agree with you, I don't try to punish anyone. What I am trying to do is *not help* someone who will not do their part to be helped. However, the vampire behavior ultimately weakens and harm the rest of the users, so some measure is to be taken to protect these other users.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes and no. Creating duplicates actually helps the system overall, since the same topic is being aliased under different keywords/angles/situations. Downvoting and closing will get rid of individual vampires eventually automatically (if the ban system works as advertised). I think what you're actually trying to do is preemptively prevent new vampires from coming in, which I don't think is possible overall. They will always come, from now until all eternity.

Comment: @Bakuriu What makes you an expert in the psychology of people who write answers?  You DON'T KNOW what their motivation is.  Do you believe in punishing them because they MIGHT be guilty of rep-whoring?

Comment: @DavidWallace Where did I say that I'm an expert in anything? And I don't see why I should be, given that SO never performed a scientific/psycological study before introducing rules/limitations. Also you are probably missing the point that I'm referring to to a *very narrow* circumstance: 1) question gets asked an closed as a duplicate almost immediately (5/10 mins) 2) The answerer *repeatedly* answer such questions instead of searching for duplicates 3) The answerer has a high reputation in the tags of the question. These 3 conditions together are very strong.

Comment: @DavidWallace Anyway, there are many ways in which we could solve such a situation. For example, once the pattern is discovered we could force these users to perform a search before allowing them to answer a question and remove this limitation after x times. If they aren't rep whoring it would just be a bit annoying for a few times, and if they are we at least try to teach them how to behave... I don't really see many downsites of such a solution.

Comment: The down side?  Let me speak as a moderately-high rep user who usually answers questions without first checking whether they're duplicates.  IF THIS SITE DOES THAT TO ME, I will give up and go join the "hyphenated site" community instead.  Either my expertise is valuable to this community or it isn't.  If I have to jump through hoops to be able to share it with people here, I just won't bother.  I imagine other people with similar levels of expertise to me would respond similarly.  Now my advice to the Stack Overflow developers would be that IF they want to destroy this site by driving ...

Comment: ... away all the moderately-expert users, then they should go ahead and implement your suggestion.  @Bakuriu

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Downvote. Move on.

With a few questions like that, the OP will first get into question rate limiter (with warnings), then, if they continue, they will end up in a question block.

Comment: And then they create a new account, and the cycle starts all over again.

Comment: Definitely need a Vampire Slayer. We already have hammers. Give us wooden stakes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ... and Silver Bullets. Well, `Mjölnir` sometimes helps to keep them away (combined with a downvote for very low research efforts perhaps).

Comment: The individual determined offender is by far the exception.  The problem is Eternal September, aka hordes of new zombie vampires pressing over the gates to replace the ones you slay (by educating them, as you so articulately explain).  In other words, educating an individual newbie won't help against the problem of all the other still uneducated newbies.

Comment: Downvote, or downvote AND flag as duplicate?

Comment: @MattCoubrough - sure, if you want.

Comment: I agree. There is really nothing more that you can do.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: the issue here is if you mark as duplicate, the question gets an answer, but if you don't, the question stays open and useless. I assume heavily downvoted questions are somewhat garbage collected, though

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Maybe remove the rep gained from every answer that posted in the last 20 minutes in the question when it gets closed?

Comment: Downvote because this doesn't really address the core of the problem.

Comment: I'd change this to, wait a bit, downvote, then move on. Too many times have I done this to be the first downvoter of a crap question only to be "countered" by sympathy upvoters trying to be "nice" and supportive. Then the outcries of "explain your votes comes in" and sucks in more sympathy upvoters. It's always net win for the vampires.

Comment: What needs to change is that one "sympathy upvote" cancels out five honest downvotes.  It's about time that the ratio of upvote-rep-delta to downvote-rep-delta was made a LOT lower than 5.

Comment: How about a 'merge questions' feature. All those questions are currently separate 'flat objects', but I think that StackOverflow (StackExchange in general) could use these questions as a information-(re)source to generate a better/more intelligent structured knowledge base, which would benefit more from 'dumb duplicate answers' than it would benefit from technically specific/precise unique questions. Sadly, my own capabilities in this area are not good, but I'd like to put the idea up so that whoever reads this might find a cool solution. :)  -I'm thinking OOP-like structures like in C++/ObjC.

Comment: This is always the answer and the community is never satisfied. Can't there be any change?

Comment: @simonzack - There can be and there is. But the need for it should be compelling. I have to admit, though, that I have no idea what change you are talking about.